# How to keep Console application open and rerun code every 5 minutes?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a Console application that I would like to run in the background.
I want it to keep the console open, and just execute the code every five minutes.

I don't want to use Windows Task Scheduler.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: You can use [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Or simply call [Thread.Sleep()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep) in your main loop if accurate timing is not critical

Comment: Why don't you want to use the windows scheduler ? it is done for that kind of task. If the process fail due to exception or anything that can freeze it the scheduler just start a new one by itself. It's a bit like asking I want peanut butter toast but I don't want to use peanut butter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
while(true)
{

  //Your Code Here
  Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

  int milliseconds = 300000;  //300000 milliseconds = 5 minutes
  Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);

}
```